# htaccess working, but layout broken?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know a huge amount about htacess and modrewrite, so I find myself in yet another predicament approaching this new zone for myself.

I will seperate my Inquiries over 2 different questions to allow answers to be on-topic and better targetted to users searching for solutions to their own questions.

This is the second of those 2 inquiries;

I have the following in my htaccess file;

```
RewriteRule ^install/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?module=faq&page=howto&program=$1
```

The concept is that **install/abcd/** would call **index.php?module=faq&page=howto&program=abcd**

That works. It pulls the content, matches it and shows what it is meant to. I have used server variables to show me what is being simulated and it matches up.

However the CSS and images on the page are being stripped as they are relative to the document, not statically assigned.

I am only using htaccess (For Now I guess?) for one solution, with the intention to soon impliment another fairly soon. The intention is to offer our customers easy to read URL's for support purposes, but not rewriting the entire site. SEO isnt a major issue as our site is only to be used by those it is intended for as opposed to a wide audience.

Other than statically assigning css, JS and image files, is there a way to fix this issue so that the page is displayed styled and with the javascript in tact?

Thanks for your help, I hope the question was understandable and as always I appreciate the time you guys take to help us all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to either make the css links absolute (starts with a /) or add a base for all our relative links by adding an extra attribute to the header:

```
<base href="/">
```

This would mean that you we start with the subdirectory of /test/. so instead of the css being;

```
http://domain.com/install/abcd/style.css
```

It would instead

```
http://domain.com/style.css
```

This is the problem I was having due to all my CSS and JS being included relativly (Allowing me to change the directory my script is in).

The above adjustment has in fact fixed my original problem, however without the use of PHP may open up an issue for some who want to be able to deploy the scripts and allow them to be fully dynamic without having to edit the base. Good luck!